# registration form in multiple pages store in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

am new in php i have a  registration in three pages.if i click a last page submit the all values should stored in db.how to do this

Comment: not sure what you are looking for, can you rephrase your question and show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to store all the values in the database you will need to pass them along the pages, maybe as hidden post fields. For example if your first page has something like

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Your second and third pages should have something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>"/ >
```

assuming that your form types are set to post.

To insert into the database when the last submit button is pressed you will need the [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) or [PDO::exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) function.

You may also want to look at [Pdo::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [PDOStatement::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to protect your site against [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the variables along as hidden form fields (see @Belinda's answer) or [store them in a session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).